# Why do Asp.net timers/updatepanels leak memory in Chrome and can it be fixed/worked around?

Tags: memory-leaks, google-chrome, updatepanel, timer, webforms

I have built a suite of internal websites for our company to manage some of our processes.  I have been noticing that these pages have massive memory leaks that cause the pages to be using well over 150mb of memory, which is ridiculous for a webpage that consists of a single form and a GridView that is displaying 7-10 rows of data at a time, sometimes with the data not changing for a whole day.  This is an issue because it is slowing down our client machines due to lack of available memory.

After some testing it appears that the memory leak is extremely easy to reproduce, and very noticeable.  I created a page with the following asp.net markup:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>    
    <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

There is absolutely no code behind for this.  This is the entirety of the page.  Running this site in Chrome shows the memory usage shoot up to 25 megs in the span of 20-30 seconds.  Leaving it running for a few minutes makes the memory go up to the 70 megs and such.

Am I using timers and update panels wrong, or is this a pure Asp.net issue with no work around?

Note: I am not talking about memory used on the server, I am talking about memory used on the client.

---

**Edit:** Well it looks like this is an issue with Chrome.  Firefox and IE8 do not seem to have any memory issues while running this page for a long period of time.

Comment: I just wanted to note that I'm having the same problem with one of our internal applications, so you're not alone.  The application makes heavy use of a Timer/UpdatePanel cycle which downloads updates from the server about every 5 seconds.  It works great in IE, but run it overnight in Chrome, and you will find every time that in the morning it has crashed the browser.  I started it about 10 minutes ago, and it was using 90MB in the Chrome Task Manager in the beginning.  Now it is using 373MB, and climbing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET isn't necessarily using all that memory.  See [How can I determine how much memory my .NET program is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357675/how-can-i-determine-how-much-memory-my-net-program-is-using)

I read a really good article about it once but I can't find it now.  I'll update this answer if I do.

**Edit:** Here's a good one: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/net-memory-usage-a-restaurant-analogy)  And one more: http://www.getdotnetcode.com/gdncstore/free/Articles/The%20Memory%20Mystery.htm

Comment: I'm not talking about memory on the server.  I am talking about memory on the client.

Comment: @KallDrexx - Oh, you mean Chrome is using that amount of memory?  Try minimizing Chrome and see if the memory drops.  It could still be similar behavior as the links I provided.  Also, try a different browser to see if you have the same memory issues.  I'll give it a try on my end as well.

Comment: Added edit to my original post.  It seems to only be an issue in Chrome, not FF or IE8.  Interesting.

Comment: @KallDrex - IE 8 doesn't have its memory shoot up.  However, generally browsing around increases the Private Working Set and it doesn't come down again.  It doesn't mean it's actually using all that.  I'm not sure I can really answer this...

Comment: @KallDrexx - Yeah, I wouldn't call it an "ASP.NET memory leak" since the browser is really handling the memory.  ASP.NET simply sends HTML and JavaScript ("text") along.  I think the closest you could come is if the ASP.NET ViewState was increasing indefinitely, but then it's technically not a memory leak.

Comment: @KallDrexx - Simply opening up Chrome (latest 5.0.375.70) to google.com uses up 40MB on my machine (Windows 7).  I'm seeing the memory jump up and down, but no apparent "leak".

Comment: Well I meant the asp.net control has a memory leak (the control's generated javascript at least).  However, this is not a viewstate issue as I am watching the viewstate and the viewstate is staying the exact same each update.

Comment: In Win 7 here at work, my chrome process at google.com uses 9MB of memory in 5.0.375.70

Comment: Note that the 40MB I'm seeing is across two different chrome.exe processes that start up.  Anyway, I don't know how to fix this.  I'm guessing it's a problem Chrome would have to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I know it have been a while since the last answer, but maybe my answer will help some one. I had similar problem. I needed timer working on background.I ended up with Update panel with the timer causing memory leak. My timer was inside the update panel. Making Update panel invisible with  `Visible:=False` solved the problem. It looks like page was redrawn every second causing major memory use buildup.